# iOS: MD5 checksum returns a different value for 32 bit and 64 bit devices. How can I resolve this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

Basically, the following code returns differently on 64 bit vs 32 bit architectures. This is currently in production code and causing a few headaches... what is causing this, and how could I fix it?

```
- (NSString *)globalIdentifier {

    // Serialize this Model instance as a JSON string
    NSDictionary *map = @{ @"title": self.title,
                           @"time": self.time, @"endtime": self.endTime,
                           @"day": self.dayNum, @"week": self.weekNum};

    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:map
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                         error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Serialization Error: %@", error);
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Now create the MD5 hash
    const char *ptr = [jsonString UTF8String];
    unsigned char md5Buffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_MD5(ptr, (unsigned int)strlen(ptr), md5Buffer);

    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x",md5Buffer[i]];

    return output;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried a known jsonString value, rather than one containing the current time? It would seem the above code would return a different value each time it was run.

Comment: @picciano yeah. I've just discovered that the JSON serialisation is unordered by nature. That's quite a big 'doh'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON serialisation is unordered by nature, and therein lies the problem.